# Extrair informação json em php

Tags: php, json

Pessoal tenho seguinte código:

```
<?php

$key = "*****************";
$forcast_days='5';
$city = '-30.1087957,-51.3169879';
$url ="http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.json?key=$key&q=$city&days=$forcast_days&=";

$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

$json_output=curl_exec($ch);
$weather = json_decode($json_output);


$days = $weather->forecast->forecastday;

echo "Cidade: ". $weather->location->name;
echo "<br>";
echo "Estado: ".$weather->location->region;
echo "<br>";
echo "Pais: ".$weather->location->country;

foreach ($days as $day){


echo "<table>";    
    echo "<tr><td colspan='4' border='0'><h2>{$day->date}</h2>";

    echo "<tr><td><h4>Wind</h4></td><td colspan='3'>{$day->day->maxwind_mph}Mph <br> {$day->day->maxwind_kph}kph </td></tr>";
    foreach ($day->hour as $hr){

        echo "<tr><td colspan='4' border='0'>";
        echo "<table style='width:100%;'>";    

        echo "<tr><td>Time</td><td>Temprature</td><td>Wind</td><td>Humidity</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td><div>{$hr->time}<img src=' {$hr->condition->icon}'/></div></td><td>{$hr->temp_c}&deg;C<br>{$hr->temp_f}&deg;F</td><td>{$hr->wind_mph}Mph <br> {$hr->wind_kph}kph</td><td>$hr->humidity</td></tr>";

        echo "</table></tr></td>";
    }
echo "</table> <br>";
```

Aqui está o resultado na web: http://ioenergias.com.br/climapesca

Como eu consigo selecionar as variáveis, por exemplo, das 00:00 até 06:00 somente?

Comment: Podes colocar um exemplo do json puro que recebes sff?

Comment: Não é oferecido o JSON. Mas tem a página com os docs da API: https://www.apixu.com/doc/forecast.aspx

Comment: Estou tentando usar algum tipo de if, para quando o horário por entre 00:00 e 06:00 ele retornar as informações, mais até agora sem sucesso.

Comment: @GustavoCave é só dar um `echo`ou `var_dump` no `$json_output` para você ver o que foi retornado. Daí você poderá postar aqui para ser ajudado.

Comment: Amigo, precisamos do retorno JSON mesmo para poder te ajudar melhor.
Mas como dica, eu, faria essa página em JavaScript e html. Fica mais fácil manipular JSON convertido em array no JavaScript.

Comment: Tentei var_dump(json_decode($json_output, true)); e ele retorna NULL

Answer (score 1):

Assim funcionaria:

```
<?php

$key = '***************************';
$forcast_days='5';
$city = '-30.1087957,-51.3169879';
$url ="http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.json?key=$key&q=$city&days=$forcast_days&=";

$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

$json_output=curl_exec($ch);
$weather = json_decode($json_output);

$days = $weather->forecast->forecastday;

foreach($days as $day) {
    echo "<h1>".date('d/m/Y', strtotime($day->date))."</h1>";

    foreach($day->hour as $hour) {
        $time = explode(' ', $hour->time);
        $time = $time[1];
        $time = explode(':', $time);
        $time = $time[0];

        if($time >= 0 and $time <= 6) {
            echo "As {$time}:00h teremos {$hour->temp_c}Cº<br>";
        }
    }
    echo '<hr>';
}
```

No retorno, peguei os dias que foram selecionados, percorri essa lista de dias, a cada elemento exibia um título com a data do dia, e dentro desse dia percorri as horas dele, no retorno notei que `$hour->time` daria uma data e hora no formato `2017-01-02 00:00` então cortei essa *string* no espaço( ) e depois nos dois pontos(:), então o resultante foi a hora do dia, assim foi fácil fazer a comparação.

Comment: Sim, funciona, mais ficou complicado para tratar o restante das infos, por exemplo, vou precisar de uma média da temperatura entre esses horários para depois mostrar alguma informação.

Comment: Deveria ter explicado na pergunta.

Comment: E não complica, é só ir incrementando uma variável com o valor da temperatura em cada hora, e no fim dividir pela quantidade de hora. Dica: melhore sua lógica.

Comment: @Ivcs CTz, preciso melhorar a lógica e a programação, sou amador.